# Trying to understand this code (pub/sub library)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is Peter Higgins's pub sub library: https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js

```
(function (d) {
    var cache = {};

    d.publish = function (topic, args) {
        cache[topic] && d.each(cache[topic], function () {
                this.apply(d, args || []);
        });
    };

    d.subscribe = function (topic, callback) {
        if (!cache[topic]) {
            cache[topic] = [];
        }
        cache[topic].push(callback);
        return [topic, callback];
    };

    d.unsubscribe = function (handle) {
        var t = handle[0];
        cache[t] && d.each(cache[t], function (idx) {
            if (this == handle[1]) {
                cache[t].splice(idx, 1);
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I don't understand the logic and the functionality of `publish`:

```
cache[topic] && d.each(cache[topic], function () {
    **this.apply(d, args || []);** //what is happening here?
});
```

What is the purpose of this part? except the fact that it publishes the event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the `&&` is used as a shorthand for:

```
if (cache[topic]) {
    d.each(cache[topic], function() { … });
}
```

This is because `&&` (and `||`) are [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so if the left hand side evaluates to a `false`-ish value (or `true`-ish value, in the case of `||`), the right hand side does not get evaluated.

For example:

```
> function foo(result) { console.log("foo"); return result; }
> function bar(result) { console.log("bar"); return result; }
> foo(false) && bar(true);
foo
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you call each topic callback (if any) with args (if any arguments are passed). So you can:

```
$.subscribe('do_something', function(str) { alert(str + ' world!')});
$.subscribe('do_something', function(str) { console.log(str)});
$.publish('do_something', ['Hello']); // will alert Hello world! and output 'Hello' to console
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cache[topic] && d.each(cache[topic], function () {
    this.apply(d, args || []);
});
```

Applying for each element of *d*, if *cache[topic]* is defined, function, which calls the *apply* method of it with *d* argument, and *args*, or an empty array, if *args* is not defined.